# Error: HTML / JQuery I can't clean the inputs when I change a select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need that when I change an option of the select, a completed field is deleted:

When `elemento_tipo` is selected, it enables loading the input `elemento_valor`, the problem is that when I change the option in `elemento_tipo` again, the field `elemento_valor` keeps the value that was entered.

I paste part of the code.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-8">
        <?php echo $fields['elemento_tipo']['label']; ?>
        <?php echo $fields['elemento_tipo']['form']; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
        <?php echo $fields['elemento_valor']['label']; ?>
        <?php echo $fields['elemento_valor']['form']; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <?php echo $fields['elemento_secundario']['label']; ?>
        <?php echo $fields['elemento_secundario']['form']; ?>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#servicio_table').DataTable({
            language: {
                url: 'plugins/datatables/spanish.json'
            },
            dom: 't',
            paging: false,
            autoWidth: false,
            searching: false,
            ordering: false,
            scrollY: '400px',
        });

        $('#elemento_valor, #elemento_secundario').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#elemento_tipo').change(function() {
            $('#elemento_valor, #elemento_secundario').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#elemento_secundario')[0].selectize.disable();
            opcion = $(this).val();
            if (jQuery.inArray(opcion, ['3', '4']) != -1) {
                $('#elemento_valor').attr('disabled', false);
            }
            if (opcion === '5') {
                $('#elemento_secundario')[0].selectize.enable();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have been assigned the task of reviewing this question, as it was asked by a new contributor. Looks good newbie. __+1__***Up***__+__